# Excel VBA userform texbox input error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will input whatever is written in the userform textbox onto the active cell. However, whenever I try to run that portion of the code, i get an error 438. Here is a sample of the part there shows up on the debug.

```
With Selection.Font
.Bold = True
End With
ActiveCell.Value = UserForm2.Controls("TextBox" & i).Caption
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Caption` be `Text` or `Value`?  AFAIK, textboxes don't have a caption.

Answer (score 0):

Error 438 means the Object doesn't support the property or method.
`Textbox.Caption` doesn't exist. For a full list of methods / properties see [MSDN TextBox Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.textbox_properties.aspx)

As on how to fix your code:
`ActiveCell.Value = UserForm2.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value`
or
`ActiveCell.Value = UserForm2.Controls("TextBox" & i).Text`